# Strange circuit at power input

Tags: power-supply, circuit-protection

I came upon this circuit at the power supply input:

[image: Power supply input]

The power is usually supplied by the VBUS pin. Now, how dows the circuit work? What is its purpose? I think it is a sort of ideal diode, but can you explain the theory behind?

Also what happens if I apply the power (5V) directly on the DCIN net?

If you are curious, this is part of the Orange Pi Zero schematic

Comment: Reverse voltage protection and the ability to power device through  DC-IN. the BJT transistor pair will turn on or off the trench MOSFET depending on VBUS & DCIN values.

Comment: Almost the same as a Schottky diode connection from Vbus to Vin.  It is good practice to use supply lines to protect inputs against static.  (Protection diodes for CMOS.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U25 transistor of pin 1,2,6 is connected to function as a diode such that pin 2 and 6 would be one E-B diode drop below VBUS.

Transistor of pin 3,4,5 with base to pin-2 would turn on when DCIN-5V is one E-B drop above. Thereby turning off the MOSFET.

The net effect is if DCIN-5V is higher than VBUS, then Q10 is turned off. Otherwise Q10 is turned on. Acting like an ideal diode with low drop out as you said.

Comment: Yes, the first transistor is used just as a diode! This is because this way the EB voltage variations (due to process, temperature, ...) are common to both transistors. Thank you!